# Getting SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fe2deb92bb0, pid=4611, tid=140613335000832 when running my java jar (flink)

Tags: java, maven, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am getting the following error soon after I run my java flink code:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fe2deb92bb0, pid=4611, tid=140613335000832
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_45-b14) (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.45-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00007fe2deb92bb0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

I have used similar code for deploying other flink jobs, but have never faced this issue. I am able to run my code in Intellij, without any issues, but when I build my code and deploy it on a server, it fails with the above fatal error.

There are few other snippets of the log file where this particular pc register shows up:

```
---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fe310009800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=4730, stack(0x00007fe317d23000,0x00007fe317e23000)]

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x00007fe2deb92bb0

Registers:
RAX=0x00007fe2deb92bb0, RBX=0x00007fe2e47b6668, RCX=0x00007fe3100068e0, RDX=0x00007fe3171db730
RSP=0x00007fe317e1dcd8, RBP=0x00007fe317e1dd20, RSI=0x00007fe317e1dd30, RDI=0x00007fe3100099f8
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x000000000000001a, R10=0x00007fe301015968, R11=0x00007fe316beee30
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x00007fe2e47b6668, R14=0x00007fe317e1dd38, R15=0x00007fe310009800
RIP=0x00007fe2deb92bb0, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010283, CSGSFS=0x002b000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000014
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e
```

```
Instructions: (pc=0x00007fe2deb92bb0)
0x00007fe2deb92b90:   
[error occurred during error reporting (printing registers, top of stack, instructions near pc), id 0xb]

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00007fe2deb92bb0 is an unknown value
RBX={method} {0x00007fe2e47b6668} 'aprMajorVersion' '()I' in 'io/netty/internal/tcnative/Library'
RCX=0x00007fe3100068e0 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00007fe3171db730: <offset 0xf99730> in /opt/deployment/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007fe316242000
RSP=0x00007fe317e1dcd8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fe310009800
RBP=0x00007fe317e1dd20 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fe310009800
RSI=0x00007fe317e1dd30 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fe310009800
RDI=0x00007fe3100099f8 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x000000000000001a is an unknown value
R10=0x00007fe301015968 is at code_begin+808 in an Interpreter codelet
method entry point (kind = native)  [0x00007fe301015640, 0x00007fe301015f40]  2304 bytes
R11=0x00007fe316beee30: <offset 0x9ace30> in /opt/deployment/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007fe316242000
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13={method} {0x00007fe2e47b6668} 'aprMajorVersion' '()I' in 'io/netty/internal/tcnative/Library'
R14=0x00007fe317e1dd38 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fe310009800
R15=0x00007fe310009800 is a thread
```

```
Stack: [0x00007fe317d23000,0x00007fe317e23000],  sp=0x00007fe317e1dcd8,  free space=1003k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x00007fe2deb92bb0
j  io.netty.internal.tcnative.Library.initialize(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z+31
j  io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.initializeTcNative(Ljava/lang/String;)Z+3
j  io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>()V+252
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x681a26]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x1056
V  [libjvm.so+0x634fd7]  InstanceKlass::call_class_initializer_impl(instanceKlassHandle, Thread*)+0xd7
V  [libjvm.so+0x636c2c]  InstanceKlass::initialize_impl(instanceKlassHandle, Thread*)+0x1ac
V  [libjvm.so+0x636fe1]  InstanceKlass::initialize(Thread*)+0x41
V  [libjvm.so+0x7e9756]  LinkResolver::resolve_static_call(CallInfo&, KlassHandle&, Symbol*, Symbol*, KlassHandle, bool, bool, Thread*)+0x246
V  [libjvm.so+0x7e99df]  LinkResolver::resolve_invokestatic(CallInfo&, constantPoolHandle, int, Thread*)+0x23f
V  [libjvm.so+0x7e9f11]  LinkResolver::resolve_invoke(CallInfo&, Handle, constantPoolHandle, int, Bytecodes::Code, Thread*)+0x4f1
V  [libjvm.so+0x67a972]  InterpreterRuntime::resolve_invoke(JavaThread*, Bytecodes::Code)+0x1b2
j  io.netty.handler.ssl.SslProvider.isAlpnSupported(Lio/netty/handler/ssl/SslProvider;)Z+40
j  reactor.netty.http.Http2SslContextSpec.lambda$static$0(Lio/netty/handler/ssl/SslContextBuilder;)V+4
j  reactor.netty.http.Http2SslContextSpec$$Lambda$319.accept(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+4
j  reactor.netty.tcp.AbstractProtocolSslContextSpec.configure(Ljava/util/function/Consumer;)Lreactor/netty/tcp/AbstractProtocolSslContextSpec;+12
j  reactor.netty.tcp.AbstractProtocolSslContextSpec.<init>(Lio/netty/handler/ssl/SslContextBuilder;)V+14
j  reactor.netty.http.Http2SslContextSpec.<init>(Lio/netty/handler/ssl/SslContextBuilder;)V+2
j  reactor.netty.http.Http2SslContextSpec.forClient()Lreactor/netty/http/Http2SslContextSpec;+7
j  reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientSecure.<clinit>()V+3
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x681a26]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x1056
V  [libjvm.so+0x634fd7]  InstanceKlass::call_class_initializer_impl(instanceKlassHandle, Thread*)+0xd7
V  [libjvm.so+0x636c2c]  InstanceKlass::initialize_impl(instanceKlassHandle, Thread*)+0x1ac
V  [libjvm.so+0x636fe1]  InstanceKlass::initialize(Thread*)+0x41
V  [libjvm.so+0x7e9756]  LinkResolver::resolve_static_call(CallInfo&, KlassHandle&, Symbol*, Symbol*, KlassHandle, bool, bool, Thread*)+0x246
V  [libjvm.so+0x7e99df]  LinkResolver::resolve_invokestatic(CallInfo&, constantPoolHandle, int, Thread*)+0x23f
V  [libjvm.so+0x7e9f11]  LinkResolver::resolve_invoke(CallInfo&, Handle, constantPoolHandle, int, Bytecodes::Code, Thread*)+0x4f1
V  [libjvm.so+0x67a972]  InterpreterRuntime::resolve_invoke(JavaThread*, Bytecodes::Code)+0x1b2
j  reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.lambda$subscribe$0(Lreactor/netty/http/client/HttpClientConnect$HttpClientHandler;Lreactor/core/publisher/MonoSink;)V+36
j  reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect$$Lambda$303.accept(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+12
j  reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;)V+21
j  reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen.subscribe(Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;Lreactor/util/retry/Retry;Lreactor/core/CorePublisher;)V+106
j  reactor.core.publisher.MonoRetryWhen.subscribeOrReturn(Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;)Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;+9
j  reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;)V+4
j  reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.subscribe(Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;)V+33
j  reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;)V+33
j  reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;)V+39
j  reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Lorg/reactivestreams/Subscriber;)V+106
j  reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(Lorg/reactivestreams/Publisher;Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;Ljava/util/function/Function;ZZ)Z+309
j  reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;)Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;+11
j  reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;)V+4
j  reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;)V+39
j  reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Lorg/reactivestreams/Subscriber;)V+106
j  reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(Lorg/reactivestreams/Publisher;Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;Ljava/util/function/Function;ZZ)Z+309
j  reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;)Lreactor/core/CoreSubscriber;+11
j  reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Lorg/reactivestreams/Subscriber;)V+61
j  reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block()Ljava/lang/Object;+10
j  com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.BlobClientBase.openInputStream(Lcom/azure/storage/blob/options/BlobInputStreamOptions;Lcom/azure/core/util/Context;)Lcom/azure/storage/blob/specialized/BlobInputStream;+180
j  com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.BlobClientBase.openInputStream(Lcom/azure/storage/blob/options/BlobInputStreamOptions;)Lcom/azure/storage/blob/specialized/BlobInputStream;+3
j  com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.BlobClientBase.openInputStream(Lcom/azure/storage/blob/models/BlobRange;Lcom/azure/storage/blob/models/BlobRequestConditions;)Lcom/azure/storage/blob/specialized/BlobInputStream;+16
j  com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.BlobClientBase.openInputStream()Lcom/azure/storage/blob/specialized/BlobInputStream;+6
j  com.phenom.analytics.streaming.HiringDataLoad.<init>(Lorg/apache/flink/api/java/utils/ParameterTool;)V+490
j  com.phenom.analytics.streaming.HiringDataLoad.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+14
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x681a26]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x1056
V  [libjvm.so+0x984f17]  Reflection::invoke(instanceKlassHandle, methodHandle, Handle, bool, objArrayHandle, BasicType, objArrayHandle, bool, Thread*)+0x5d7
V  [libjvm.so+0x9885e7]  Reflection::invoke_method(oopDesc*, Handle, objArrayHandle, Thread*)+0x147
V  [libjvm.so+0x70f5ab]  JVM_InvokeMethod+0x26b
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+100
J 1261 C1 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (10 bytes) @ 0x00007fe30141458c [0x00007fe301414480+0x10c]
J 1260 C1 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; (62 bytes) @ 0x00007fe301414d54 [0x00007fe301414960+0x3f4]
j  org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/String;)V+244
j  org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution()V+11
j  org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(Lorg/apache/flink/core/execution/PipelineExecutorServiceLoader;Lorg/apache/flink/configuration/Configuration;Lorg/apache/flink/client/program/PackagedProgram;ZZ)V+76
j  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(Lorg/apache/flink/configuration/Configuration;Lorg/apache/flink/client/program/PackagedProgram;)V+11
j  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run([Ljava/lang/String;)V+113
j  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun([Ljava/lang/String;)I+398
j  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(Lorg/apache/flink/client/cli/CliFrontend;[Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Integer;+2
j  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend$$Lambda$91.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+8
j  org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.HadoopSecurityContext$$Lambda$92.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+4
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x681a26]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x1056
V  [libjvm.so+0x7197dc]  JVM_DoPrivileged+0x27c
J 448  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedExceptionAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (0 bytes) @ 0x00007fe3011e2f55 [0x00007fe3011e2e80+0xd5]
j  javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Ljavax/security/auth/Subject;Ljava/security/PrivilegedExceptionAction;)Ljava/lang/Object;+42
j  org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(Ljava/security/PrivilegedExceptionAction;)Ljava/lang/Object;+14
j  org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(Ljava/util/concurrent/Callable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+15
j  org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+66
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x681a26]  JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*)+0x1056
V  [libjvm.so+0x6c3692]  jni_invoke_static(JNIEnv_*, JavaValue*, _jobject*, JNICallType, _jmethodID*, JNI_ArgumentPusher*, Thread*)+0x362
V  [libjvm.so+0x6e009a]  jni_CallStaticVoidMethod+0x17a
C  [libjli.so+0x7bcc]  JavaMain+0x80c
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x7e75]  start_thread+0xc5
```

I do not have enough knowledge about java to debug this issue, can someone help out?

Tried running it in different environments, only IntelliJ build and run is working.
Expecting to resolve the fatal error, or atleast find the root cause of it so I can deploy my java code.

Comment: The JVM version is ancient. This is probably a JVM bug. Try with a current release of JDK 8.